# How to view the contents of activity in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to view the contents of activity in a fragment, I have a table in activity that contains statistics and I want to compare it with other table in a fragment How can I do This?

Comment: Show your code here please...

Comment: Why the whole question is bolded?

Answer (score 0):

When you starting fragment put extra bundle into it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739968/5577679

Or (wrong way) set that table to be static and just use it as it is part of the fragment:

```
String row1 = getActivity.yourTable[0];
```

Comment: the table is a tablelayout

Comment: I didn't finish writing it yet

Answer (score 0):

In your activity create a function

```
public Table getYourTableStatistics(){
   return yourTable;
}
```

in your fragment use it like

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).getYourTableStatistics();
```

Comment: the table is tableLayout

Comment: Create a function a function for table layout then. Access it like mentioned above